# Getting values on twig node template

Tags: theming, 8, nodes

I have installed [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) module in my website. Using it I have created a "report eck" entity in which I have different bundles like section, notes, etc., each containing different fields.
I have my content type "Report" in which I have referred "report eck" entity using entity reference field.
Now, in my nice template, I need to get various values including the bundle type, in which I am facing lots of trouble. My bundle type is coming up as following when I am doing kint() on my reference field, but I am not able to get this bundle type and many other values, please guide.
[image]

Also, it seems to be a protected values, so I navigated to "Available Methods" tabs and found method 'getEntityKey()' which seems to be useful, but how can I use it in twig template??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are protected. You need to use any available getters to access them. Example, for nodes, the method is `getType()`. `$node->getType()`. Most generic entities should have a `bundle()` method that returns type.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Abundle/8.4.x

Examples:

`$bundle = $myEntity->bundle();`

`$variables['bundle'] = $bundle;`

Twig: `{{ bundle }}`

Comment: I found some methods in the 'Available Methods' tab, but how to implement them in a twig template?

Comment: You can't implement PHP methods or PHP code in a twig template. You can only inject new variables from the .theme file in a preprocess hook.

Comment: I know I can not implement PHP in twig template, but I thought there will be some way to access these variables in template, I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: His code example is for twig template not PHP one.

Answer (score 0):

I will go for `render` option and use the template instead of manually accessing values. Alternatively, you can go for [custom twig functions or filters](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates) to access referenced field values.